# extract the value use by these two data frame

Tags: python, pandas

two column of 1 data frame and other two column of 2nd data frame now extract the value use by these two data frame

```
df1[["source", "Tar"]       df2["id", "me"]

source    Tar                  id        me
cd1        ef2                 60_2       ac4
cd1       hi1                 50_6        xg3
zx2        an2
cd1      60_2
zx2      50_6
```

Output should be

```
df1["source" , "Tar"]

source    Tar                  
cd1       ef2                 
cd1       hi1                 
zx2       an2
cd1       ac4
zx2       xg3
```

Comment: Please do not ask twice the same question. Rather improve the first one with more details if needed.

Comment: but i m not getting useful answer

Comment: This likely means you have not properly asked the question. Please read carefully [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular the part on [**minimal reproducible examples**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which you haven't provided (your example does **not** reproduce your real data as it has no duplicates).